# Why Is the base class also called "super" class in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, type-conversion

If answer is yes, I am very curious why?

In msdn, "For reference types, an implicit conversion always exists from a class to any one of its direct or indirect base classes or interfaces. No special syntax is necessary because a derived class always contains all the members of a base class."

Isn't derived class more "super" than base class, because "a derived class always contains all the members of a base class." and plus more, right?

Comment: In general base and super are just other ways to refer to the parent class in OOP.

Comment: It is an ambiguous term.  It depends on how you draw the inheritance tree.  You can start the base at the bottom, growing up, or on the top of the image, growing down.  Both styles are used.  But in general "super" does refer to the base class and "sub" to a more derived class.  The C++/CLI managed language has the [`__super` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x.aspx).  "Base" and "derived" are never ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 'base' refers to the parent class, and 'derived' refers to the child class.

'super' is in reference to being above, not having more. ie: parent.

Comment: this doesn't answer "why" it's called `super`. My answer below makes an attempt at that

Answer (score 3):

## It may come from "subset"/"superset" in mathematics.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset.

Basically, suppose you had this:

```
public class Parent { }

public class Child : Parent { }
```

All Childs are Parents (because Child extends Parent), so all Childs are a subset of Parent / Parent is a `super`set of Child.

Comment: Though "Conceptually, a derived class is a specialization of the base class",  "the derived class extends the functionality of the base class" in MSDN. It means "In the derived class, you can **add more members**". Mathematically, not all elements of Childs are in Parents.

Comment: @MikeLiu We're not talking about the attributes/components of Childs and Parents. We're just talking about the types Child and Parent. Don't think about the `has-a` relationships. Think about the `is-a` relationship. From wiki: `B is a superset of A if all elements of A are also elements of B`. Every Child is a  Parent - matching `all elements of A are also elements of B` imo. It's not that every B is an A (A is more specialized), but every A is indeed a B.

Comment: @MikeLiu - I think there is some confusion on the term "every element of A". You're taking it to mean every attribute/property of the class `Child`. I'm taking it to mean every instance/object of the class `Child`. I think in this case, my understanding of the meaning is more appropriate

Comment: In math: " B is a superset of A, if A is "contained" inside B, that is, all elements of A are also elements of B. " But in C#, subclass A can **add more elements** when inheriting from superclass B; i.e. A is not totally "conained" inside B. There **is** some confusion.

Comment: You're treating the set A as a particular single thing - which it's not. It's a Set - represents all of the A things. So an element of a A *is* an A thing, not an element of an A thing.